# Cannot install any OS!

Tags: windows, installation

I had Win7 Build 7100 and found that my internet connection wasn't working because of the known bug with rapppoe.sys. I didn't manage to fix it so I burned Build 7600 and tried to make a clean install. I have 2 hard-disks (150 GB and 500 GB). When I reached the menu with the partitions I formated C: and then tried to install the system on that, but I got this:

> Setup was unable to create a new
>   system partition or locate an existing
>   system partition. See the Setup log
>   files for more information.

The smaller hdd was split in three but finally I formated all of it, but I hope I can recover some pictures from it after I manage to install the system.

I tried Vista SP2 but also gave an error, tried XP but it says something is wrong with the partition, that they are RAW partitions. I managed to create new partitions with diskpart using the Command Prompt, but same thing. Converting them directly from RAW to NTSF didn't work, as it said that:

> Convert is not available for RAW
>   drives.

I read it is something about RAID and removing some drives for the convert problem, but right now I'm writing from my phone. I know that the bigger hdd is SATA and the other one I think is ATA. I'm a med student and I have important data on the big hdd so I can't use it to install the system (it's dynamic anyway). Now I have the small hdd split in 2: one 100 gb created with disk part and one 50 gb created in the Win7 install menu.

I'm desperate, please help me out!

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Could you organized that so we can read it and help with your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if all your important data is on the big hard drive the best way to secure it is to shut down the PC and unplug the drive until your done.  Next I think you'll need to delete the existing partitions on the smaller hard drive when given the option in the installer and start from a clean disk.

After you've installed reconnect the big hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

What about GParted (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)? It is a Live Linux CD. GParted is basically used for repartitioning your system; ofcourse you can simply delete all partitions, create your own as you desire etc.

Another thing - you might want to try low level format if toying with Gparted won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Nuke it from orbit, its the only way to be sure

1) backup everything you'll need from the drive you want to install to. Unplug the other drive... in case.
2) run [dban](http://www.dban.org/) on the disk you want to install to. yes, it'll take a while and totally irrecoverably wipe your hard drive so doublecheck you have wiped the drive. Let it wipe the drive
3) install an OS.

Comment: Isn't DBAN a bit overkill for something like this?

Comment: i've had a few cases where windows refused to see the drive. It *is* a little overkill, but if nothing else failed, this method generally will work.

Comment: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda worked for me. Used a SLAX disk.